# How to exclude package from being installed via symlink in pnpm?

Tags: node.js, electron, pnpm

I have an Electron project and used `pnpm` due to it's significant speedup when installing modules over `npm` or `yarn`.

However, **1** module has a problem by being installed via a symlink in the `node_modules` directory. Is there any way to exclude a dependency from becoming a symlink?

As far as I understood the documentation, a `.npmrc` file with the setting below should be enough, but it doesn't work:

```
hoist-pattern[]=*nodegit*
```

Comment: Have you tried using also shamefully-hoist=true in your .npmrc?

Comment: I give that a try! Thank you! I will report soon if it fixed it

Comment: I just tried that, modules starting with`@` seem to be hardlinked, everything else is still symlinked, so is `nodegit` :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**New answer:**

As of v7.13, you can set [node-linker=hoisted](https://pnpm.io/npmrc#node-linker) in a `.npmrc` in the root of your project. pnpm will create a flat node_modules like the one created by npm or Yarn, without using symlinks at all.

**Old answer:**

As of version 5.14, the only way to avoid symlinks with pnpm is to use the [Plug'n'Play feature](https://pnpm.io/en/npmrc#node-linker) and set the [symlink](https://pnpm.io/en/npmrc#symlink) setting to false. You can create a `.npmrc` in the root of you project with the following content:

```ini
node-linker=pnp
symlink=false
```

---

Using the hoist settings you can only reduce the number of symlinks, not avoid them. This blog post should explain the different configurations: [Node-Modules configuration options with pnpm](https://pnpm.io/blog/2020/10/17/node-modules-configuration-options-with-pnpm). With `hoist=false`, you'll get the minimal amount of symlinks.

Plug'n'Play is known to still have lots of issues, so if it doesn't help, feel free to ask for help in the [pnpm discord channel](https://discord.gg/CeZ7xK2bvJ) or create an issue [in our repository](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/).

Comment: node-linker=hoisted exclude all packages from symlink, not expecific package

Comment: There is no way to partially disable symlinks. If you mean just symlinks for hoisting to the root of node_modules, then you can do something like this:

```
public-hoist-pattern[]=*
public-hoist-pattern[]=!lodash
```

This will symlink everything except lodash to the root of node_modules